# Update laravel database

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-query-builder

I know if i want to update database on laravel i could just use

```
$user = User::find($request->id);
$user->name = $request->get(‘name’);
$user->save();
```

But what if my table doesn’t have id column in it? It primary column name isn’t id? I’ve tried this method and it didn’t work

```
$user = User::where(‘userID’, $request->id);
$user->name = $request->get(‘name’);
$user->save();
```

This are my table content

accountReceiveAble

1. sales - PK
2. invoice
3. taxInvoice
4. dpp
5. ppn
6. paymentDate
7. payementMethod

This are my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $ra = accountRecieveAble::where('sales',$request->sales)->firstOrFail();
        $ra->invoice = $request->get('invoice');
        $ra->taxInvoice = $request->get('taxInvoice');
        $ra->dpp = $request->get('dpp');
        $ra->ppn = $request->get('ppn');
        $ra->paymentDate = $request->get('date');
        $ra->paymentMethod = $request->get('method');
        $ra->save();
        return redirect(action('AccountRecieveAbleController@index'));
    }
```

this are my model

```
class accountRecieveAble extends Model
{
  protected $table = "account_recieve_ables";
  public $primaryKey = 'sales';
  public $timestamps =false;

  public function sale(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\sales','sales');
  }
}
```

Comment: `dd($user)` and show us what it is returning? Second why would you not want PK in your table any specific reason?

Comment: It said ‘Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::save()’ it’s my mistake naming that way...

Comment: then do as Milan suggested in answer i.e append `first()` if you want a single row or `get()` if you want all.

Comment: It still search column id for update instead using column sales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the `primary key` to something else other than `id`, you need to override it in your Model.

```
class YourModel
{
    /**
     * Your primary key column name.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    $primaryKey = 'sales';
}
```

Also, if it is non integer value, then again, you will have to add the following to your model..

```
class YourModel
{
    /**
     * Your primary key column name.
     *
     * @var integer
     */
     protected $primaryKey = 'sales';

     /**
      * If your primaryKey is not integer or non numeric value
      * 
      * @var string
      */
     protected $keyType = 'string';

     /**
      * And if it is not going to increment the value
      * 
      * @var boolean
      */
     public $incrementing = false;
}
```

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#defining-models) - Scroll down to `Primary Keys` section:

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named id. You may define a protected `$primaryKey` property to override
>   this convention.

Comment: it work but work somereason it said invalid datetime format

Comment: **SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'B250119' for column 'invoice' at row 1 (SQL: update `account_recieve_ables` set `invoice` = B250119, `taxInvoice` = 41, `dpp` = 41, `ppn` = 41, `paymentDate` = 2019-01-25, `paymentMethod` = b where `sales` = 2)** these are the error comment

Comment: The error says it all.. You are passing the wrong date time format with the payload.. Whatever your datetime format is in the database table column, you should pass in that format only.

Answer (score 1):

In this query `$user = User::where(‘userID’, $request->id);` append first() like this `$user = User::where(‘userID’, $request->id)->first();`

Comment: It looking for column id which I don’t have column id. My pk column are ‘sales’